# incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UILabel *__weak' to 'NSString *__strong'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, string

i've been doing a thing here using objective-c, but i'm a beginner in this language, and that's what i did:

there is a class, named "firstviewclass", that is in the control of my first view, in this view there is a textfield that the user puts a number. the textfield is in the firstviewclass.h named "setNumber". There is another class, named "secondviewclass" that is in control of the second view, in this view there is a label that is in the secondviewclass.h, and i want that this label recive the value that the user put in the textfield from the first view. my codes:

firstviewclass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface firstviewclass : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *setNumber;

- (IBAction)gotonextview:(id)sender;

 @end
```

secondviewclass.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "firstviewclass.h"

@interface secondviewclass : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue;

@end
```

secondviewclass.m:

```
#import "secondviewclass.h"
#import "firstviewclass.h"

@implementation secondviewclass
@synthesize labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue;


-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    firstviewclass *object = [[firstviewclass alloc] init];

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", [object.setNumber.text intValue]];

    labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue = string; //here is where that error appears "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UILabel *__weak' to 'NSString *__strong'"

}

@end
```

I've changed what you had told me to change, but when i test it on the simulator any number that i put in the textfield it appears in the label as 0... i really don't know what to do!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be:

```
labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue.text = string;
```

---

**Under the hood:**

After your xib instantiated  an `UILabel` and you get its reference using the `IBOutlet` keyword, you are then trying to use the `UILabel` pointer to point to a space in memory allocated and instantiated for a `NSString`, that's why you are having this problem. You probably also did get a warning about that assignment you tried to do:

```
labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue = string;
```

You should always try to fix warnings.

**What you want:**

You simply want the `UILabel` to display the `NSString` you just created, and for that you should use the `UILabel's` text property.

Comment: +1 for correct answer - even though a little explanation would have been nice.

Comment: I've changed what you had told me to change, but when i test it on the simulator any number that i put in the textfield it appears in the label as 0... i really don't know what to do!

Comment: "incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString* from UILabel*" Got this warning... Had Nothing at all to do with assigning the incompatible pointer types (Which I DEFINED...) But Thanks to XCodes Wonderful, Let us Synthesize your methods and write your Getters & Setters for you, I spent 30 minutes Trying to find out why ONLY one of my UILabel Functions was giving this warning...  IS There any way under God's green earth to add a compiler flag to DISABLE this "Synthesizing?"

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because you are pointing a label to a string. They are of different classes, so that's not allowed. What you really mean is that you want the text on your label to take the value of the string. So you need to set the text field of the label:

```
labelthatrecivesthetextfieldvalue.text = string;
```

My apologies for my earlier, incorrect answer.

Incidentally, you should also consider using camelCase for naming your variables. That is the convention for objective-c. ie call it `labelThatRecievesTheTextFieldValue` instead. This doesnt affect the ability of your code to work, just convention.

Comment: That is absolutely not the problem.  Strong and weak are storage qualifiers, they do not modify the class of the object.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! This is now a brand new answer. consider redeeming me?

Comment: @aking63 +1 for compensation.

Comment: your answer was helpfull too... i don't now how to compensate you, what is this +1 thing?

Comment: it just means they pressed the up arrow beside my answer. I get a couple reputation points for it. Its a good thing to do if you thing someone's answer was helpful to you or shows particular effort.

Comment: okok but i can't yet... i need to have at least 15 reputation points! but i promise that i'll do it sooner i can!